# Let $V$ be a non-zero finite dimensional complex vector space and let $T\in L(V)$ be a linear operator, then $T$ has an eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a non-zero finite dimensional complex vector space and let $T\in L(V)$ be a linear operator, then $T$ has an eigenvalue.

I'm trying to solve the above exercise problem as follows:

Let dim $V=n$. Let $P_n(\mathbb C)$ be the set of all polynomials of degree $n$ over complex field $\mathbb C$. Since $V$ is non-zero, there exists a $v\in V$ such that $v\ne 0$. Let $f: P_n(\mathbb C)\to V$ be defined as $f(p)=p(T)v$.

Since dim ($P_n(\mathbb C))\gt n, f$ can't be 1-1. Hence, there exists a non-constant $p\in P_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $f(p)=0\implies p(T)v=0$. Let's assume that $p$ is of the lowest degree such that $$p(T)v=0 \tag 1$$

Let $p(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$, where $n\ge m\ge 1$ and $a_m\ne 0$. By fundamental theorem of algebra, $p(x)=a_m(x-\alpha_1) f_1(x)$ for some $\alpha_1\in \mathbb C$. It follows that $p(T)=a_m(T-\alpha_1I)p_1(T)$. It follows by $(1)$ that $a_m(T-\alpha_1I)p_1(T)v=0\implies (T-\alpha_1I)(p_1(T)v)=0$. Noting that degree $p_1$ is smaller than degree of $p(x)$, it follows that $p_1(T)v$ is non zero and hence $T-\alpha_1I$ is not 1-1. It follows that $\alpha_1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Background:  This is an exercise problem from section 5.B of Sheldon Axler's linear algebra textbook. I understand that the exercise wants to prove the statement using function $f$ as I have defined above.

Comment: The easiest way to approach is by observing that eigenvalues of a linear operator are roots of the characteristic polynomial of $T$ and then use fundamental theorem of algebra to conclude.

Comment: @AntonioClaire: I have used the same thing. :)

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and quite well-written too!

Comment: @TheoBendit: Thanks a lot for review :)